# Find count from string column with numeric values

Tags: php, mongodb, count

I have dataset where the numeric columns are also in string type.

And I need the count of rows where the value is greater than 5 and less than 60. Since it is a string column it has comma separated numbers in it.

The values in database in this column are like

```
98,800
40,857.06
5
500
1,250
40
```

Code:

```
$rangeQuery = array('NumberInt(this.turnover_GBP_LT)' => array( '$gt' => 5, '$lt' => 100 ));

$cursor = $collection->count($rangeQuery);
```

I am getting the count as 0 though there are values available in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below php code

```
$numbers = array('98,800',
'40,857.06',
'5',
'500',
'1,250',
'40');

$min = 5;
$max = 100;
$count =  count(array_filter(
    $numbers,
    function ($value) use($min,$max) {
        $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        return ($value > $min && $value < $max);
    }
));
```

Comment: I gave sample values..there are more than 10,000 rows in the mongodb collection...it won't work